# Python - Unable to import '...' when __init__.py file is in directory

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have the following directory structure :

```
myproject
  __init__.py
  src
    __init__.py
    main.py
    common
      __init__.py
      logging
        __init__.py
        setup.py
```

All init files are empty.

Why is it that in `main.py` I cannot do :
`from src.common.logging import *`

I get an error stating it is unable to import. I thought the `__init__.py` files here would have prevented this from happening.

I've tried `from common.logging import *` as well, but didn't work either.

Ideally I don't want to add anything to my path and I was expecting this to work with only `__init__.py` files in a clean/pythonic way.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer.

It was actually my linter complaining that the import was not possible, but this was due to a wrong python path specified in my editor. When executing the code, all imports worked fine.

I was using `visual studio code`.

Make sure you set your python path in settings.json

```
"python.pythonPath": "/__venv__/bin/python3"
```